# How to print a name by a given ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arraylist, javascript-objects

```js
var people = [
    {name: 'John', id: [34, 44, 77]},
    {name: 'Jose', id: [43, 54, 65]},
    {name: 'Hanna', id: [56, 34, 98]}
];

var peopleFinder = people.filter(function(b){
    return b.id === 56;
}).map(function(n2){
    return n2.name;
})
console.log(peopleFinder);
```

How to print an name from an array of objects, by a given ID. This has to be solve without using any type of loops. Just array methods are allow to be use: .filter(), .map(), .reduce() and .find().

Comment: Since `id` is an array you can't use `b.id === 56`. Use another array method like `includes` to make sure the `id` is in the array.

Comment: `const peopleFinder = id => people.find(e=>e.id.includes(id))?.name;` will be fine...(?)

Comment: check my `Array::reduce()` solution, seems faster

Comment: does it allows to find several names? for example id 34 has 2 names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, since the id property in each object is an array, you need to use the `.includes()` method to check if the given ID exists within the array.
Please check below code and try, i have made some changes:

```js
var people = [
  {name: 'John', id: [34, 44, 77]},
  {name: 'Jose', id: [43, 54, 65]},
  {name: 'Hanna', id: [56, 34, 98]}
];

var peopleFinder = people.filter(function(person) {
  return person.id.includes(56);
}).map(function(person) {
  return person.name;
});

console.log(peopleFinder);
```

In this code, the `filter()` method is used to find the objects that have the ID 56 in their id array. The `includes()` method is used to perform the check. Then, the `map()` method is used to extract the name property from the filtered objects.

Hope this will help !

Comment: Answers (even those that work) should not just be code. You should explain what the problem was and how your code solves it.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Just make sure you check if the `id` array [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the id you're looking for and don't compare by value:

```js
var people = [
  {name: "John", id: [34, 44, 77]},
  {name: "Jose", id: [43, 54, 65]},
  {name: "Hanna", id: [56, 34, 98]}
];

const id = 56;

const name = people.filter(p => p.id.includes(id)).map(p => p.name);
console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first we need to filter out the ones that dont have the id we are searching for. For that we user `filter()`.

```js
var peopleFinder = people
  .filter(function(person) {
    return person.id.includes(idToFind);
  })
```

In more detail, what the filter function does is filters the array to only include the items that match out criteria.

After that we have to map our user's name, so we user the `map()` function.

```js
  .map(function(person) {
    return person.name;
  });
```

Then by putting them both together we should get the name of the person with the Id we need.

```js
var peopleFinder = people
  .filter(function(person) {
    return person.id.includes(idToFind);
  })
  .map(function(person) {
    return person.name;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

An `Array::reduce()` compact version:

```js
const people = [
  {name: "John", id: [34, 44, 77]},
  {name: "Jose", id: [43, 54, 65]},
  {name: "Hanna", id: [56, 34, 98]}
];
const idToFind = 34;
console.log(people.reduce((result, {name, id}) => {
  id.includes(idToFind) && result.push(name);
  return result;
}, []));
```

And a benchmark:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1">

    const chunk = [
        { name: 'John', id: [34, 44, 77] },
        { name: 'Jose', id: [43, 54, 65] },
        { name: 'Hanna', id: [56, 34, 98] }
    ];

    let people = [];

    let count = 5000000;
    while (count--) {
        people.push(...chunk);
    }

    const idToFind = 34;

    // @benchmark Kedar's solution
    people.filter(function (person) {
        return person.id.includes(idToFind);
    }).map(function (person) {
        return person.name;
    });


    // @benchmark Alexander's solution
    people.reduce((result, { name, id }) => {
        id.includes(idToFind) && result.push(name);
        return result;
    }, []);


</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Just for fun, don't try to reproduce at home, a regex version :)

```js
var people = [
  {name: 'John', id: [34, 44, 77]},
  {name: 'Jose', id: [43, 54, 65]},
  {name: 'Hanna', id: [56, 34, 98]}
];

const id = 34;
const regex = new RegExp(`(?<=name":")[^"]+(?=","id":\\[[\\d,]*(?<=\\D)${id})`, 'g');
console.log(JSON.stringify(people).match(regex))
```

Comment: `{
  id.includes(idToFind) && result.push(name);
  return result;
}` could be `id.includes(idToFind) ? [...result, name] : result`

Comment: @JollyJoker could be but performance will suffer significantly because of the array copying

Comment: I like your seeking for performance improvements yet I think, sometimes its just better to write straight forward code that everyone can comprehense easily instead of overcomplicating things for an array of length 3.

Comment: @Behemoth folks should do better than es5. legacy js is buggy. programmers should learn modern version of languages

Comment: @Behemoth using var is a crime nowadays

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#find` method as follows:

```js
const 
      people = [ {name: 'John', id: [34, 44, 77]}, {name: 'Jose', id: [43, 54, 65]}, {name: 'Hanna', id: [56, 34, 98]} ],
      
      id = 56,
      
      person = people.find(p => p.id.includes(id))?.name || 'not found';
      
console.log( person );
```